# why can't i use list iterator logical comparisons operator?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

It's very basic, but I could not find a similar question here. I am trying to iterate the same sorted STL list from different directions using list. I know I can compare an iterator to the `list.begin()` and `list.end()`, so why doesn't this work?

```
list<family>::iterator itLargeFamily = 
                  families.begin(); //starts from the biggest families
list<family>::iterator itSmallFamily = 
                  families.end(); //starts from the smallest families

for (; itSmallFamily > itLargeFamily; --itSmallFamily, ++itLargeFamily) {
    // stuff...
}
```

The error is of course

> no operator > matches these operands

100% chance I'm missing something basic.

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve with this kind of comparison?

Comment: moving through the list with two independent iterators. the  itSmallFamily-- and itLargeFamily++ above is for simplicity of the example. i would need to advance/decrease them independent of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments and the answer of sftrabbit you can see that relational operators are only defined for random access iterators,  and `std::list` has only bidirectional iterators. So there are several solutions for your problem:

1. Use `std::vector` or `std::array`. They provide random access iterators, have better performance for smaller sizes, and depending of how you fill/use them for larger sizes as well, and they have better memory footprint. This is the preferred solution, I'd call it the "default" solution. Use other containers only if there is a very good, measurable reason (e.g. a profiler tells you that using that container is a performance bottleneck).
2. Since you know the size of the list, you can use a counter for your iterations:

   ```
   for (size_t i = 0, count = families.size()/2; 
        i < count; 
        ++i, --itSmallFamily, ++itLargeFamily)
   { /* do stuff */ }
   ```
3. Since your list is sorted, you can compare the elements the iterators point to instead of the iterators themselves.

Comment: thank you. for 3. i'm using a fairly complex  "families.sort(compare_size)" code (not really complex, but enough to write it someplace else the iterating code.

Comment: @PIXP therefore it's only point 3 in the list ;-) If the comparison is expensive, that is not an option.

Comment: not expensive with runtime, more like cumbersome. and the comment was for future readers...

Answer (score 4):

Only random access iterators are ordered. `std::list` iterators are only bidirectional iterators, so they do not support `operator<` or `operator>`.

Instead, you could do your comparison with `!=`.

```
while (itSmallFamily != itLargeFamily)
```

You'll have to make sure that the iterators don't jump over each other for this to work though. That is, if `itSmallFamily` is only one increment away from `itLargeFamily`, you will simply swap them over and they'll never have been equal to each other.

You could instead use `std::vector`, whose iterators are random access iterators. In addition, `std::array` and `std::deque` are also support random access.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. so i guess it was nothing i missed, it's just lack of basic knowledge on my side. are there any iterators (from other containers maybe) that can be compared across the container like i have described?

Comment: This will only work if `(families.size() % 2) == 0 ` since else those iterators will never be the same.

Comment: @PIXP `std::vector` has random access iterators.

Comment: @sftrabbit is that a different definition of "ordered" than [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library#Containers) is?

Comment: @PIXP: `std::vector` is almost always a better choice than `std::list`. `std::list` is good if you're doing many inserts at arbitrary locations _and_ the number of elements is significant (hundreds, maybe even thousands).

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes. That's talking about ordering elements of the container, while this is about the ordering of iterators.